# IntelliJ project errors "/hello.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource"

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404

My web.xml contains

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Directory structure is

```
-web
---WEB-INF
     faces-config.xml
     web.xml
---hello.xhtml
```

I know that there are many questions like this on stackoverflow but they didn't help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your hello.xhtml is not located under `faces/` as it is configured: `<welcome-file>faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file>`

Comment: change this line <welcome-file>faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file> to <welcome-file>hello.xhtml</welcome-file>

Comment: I tried with <welcome-file>hello.xhtml</welcome-file> , i tried deleting faces folder and other combinations

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that IntelliJ Idea configured non-existed folder as web resources. 
Project Structure -> Facets -> Web, then i changed web resources directory path ti actual web folder. That resolved the issue.